# Drawing over an existing image using SkiaSharp in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

My requirements I have is that I'm passed a raw string and need to create a drawing canvas for users to draw over. By "drawing" I'm referring to a user drawing with their finger on the mobile screen. Here is what I found.

What it does is create a a very narrow canvas (resizing is a separate issue) that is blank. It is able to draw very short strokes, but drawing a new stroke removes other strokes. I'm also able to draw dots that don't seem to be removed.

I think the problem is a fundamental misunderstanding of how `OnPainting` Works. My understanding is it redraws the canvas each time, which is what the dictionary of strokes is for. This code is lifted from the SkiaSharp demo which works nicely, but just has a white background.

The code below is my attempt at repurposing the demo to have a background image, but my modifications have failed to render the image and broken the drawing functionality.

My code:

```
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace redacted
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DrawingSurface : ContentView
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<long, SKPath> temporaryPaths = new Dictionary<long, SKPath>();
        private readonly List<SKPath> paths = new List<SKPath>();

        SKBitmap background = null;

        public DrawingSurface()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public DrawingSurface(string rawImagePNG64bit) : base()
        {
            background = SKBitmap.Decode(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(rawImagePNG64bit)));
        }

        public void Clear()
        {

            //TODO
        }
        
        #region TouchDrawing
        private void OnPainting(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            
            SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
            // we get the current surface from the event args
            var surface = e.Surface;
            // then we get the canvas that we can draw on
            var canvas = surface.Canvas;
            // clear the canvas / view
            if(background != null)
            {
                canvas.DrawBitmap(background, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);
            }

            if (background != null)
            {
                var resizedBitmap = background.Resize(info, SKBitmapResizeMethod.Box);

                canvas.DrawBitmap(resizedBitmap, info.Width / 2 - resizedBitmap.Width / 2, info.Height / 2 - resizedBitmap.Height / 2);
            }

            // DRAWING TOUCH PATHS

            // create the paint for the touch path
            var touchPathStroke = new SKPaint
            {
                IsAntialias = true,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
                Color = SKColors.Red,
                StrokeWidth = 3
            };

            // draw the paths
            foreach (var touchPath in temporaryPaths)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(touchPath.Value, touchPathStroke);
            }
            foreach (var touchPath in paths)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(touchPath, touchPathStroke);
            }
        }
        private void OnTouch(object sender, SKTouchEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.ActionType)
            {
                case SKTouchAction.Pressed:
                    // start of a stroke
                    var p = new SKPath();
                    p.MoveTo(e.Location);
                    temporaryPaths[e.Id] = p;
                    break;
                case SKTouchAction.Moved:
                    // the stroke, while pressed
                    if (e.InContact && temporaryPaths.TryGetValue(e.Id, out var moving))
                        moving.LineTo(e.Location);
                    break;
                case SKTouchAction.Released:
                    // end of a stroke
                    if (temporaryPaths.TryGetValue(e.Id, out var releasing))
                        paths.Add(releasing);
                    temporaryPaths.Remove(e.Id);
                    break;
                case SKTouchAction.Cancelled:
                    // we don't want that stroke
                    temporaryPaths.Remove(e.Id);
                    break;
            }

            // update the UI
            if (e.InContact)
                ((SKCanvasView)sender).InvalidateSurface();

            // we have handled these events
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The XAML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="redacted"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             
             >
    
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <views:SKCanvasView x:Name        ="DrawingCanvas" 
                            PaintSurface      ="OnPainting" 
                            EnableTouchEvents ="True" 
                            Touch             ="OnTouch" />
        </Grid>
        
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: You could look at the [Finger Painting in SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/finger-paint).

Comment: I've looked into it. It seems to work, but has some of the same problems I'm facing. I'm now realizing that having a drawing object inside a scroll view is causing issues.  When I get it working I'll post my solution.